# How to write child record using itemWriter in spring batch

Tags: java, spring-batch

my situation:

I have class A which I read from db in readerItem. Then I need to processing this class A and create class B which I am doing in itemProcessor. And finally I save this class B into db in itemWriter.

Problem: In processing I also need to create class C (about 1 mil records) which has foreign key of class B and save this class C. How should I do this.

I cant do something like this:
Because as I wrote I have about 1 mil records which should I need to store in memory what is about 2gb of space. SO how should I solve this problem.

```
public class BWriter extends BaseItemWriter<B> {

    public void write(List<? extends B> data) throws Exception {
        logger.info("Start writing: " + data);
        for (B item : data) {
            myCustomDao.saveB(item);
            for (C itemC : item.getC()) {
                itemC.setB(item);
                myCustomDao.saveC(itemC);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

UPDATE:

possible solution which doesnt include spring batch which I want:

```
    List<C> cList = new ArrayList<C>();
    int i = 0;
    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] data = line.split(";");
        if (data.length > 1 && !StringUtils.isBlank(data[1])) {
            C cItem = new C();
            cItem.set(...);
            cList.add(i, cItem);
            if (++i >= 1000) {
                myCustomDao.save(cList);
                cList = new ArrayList<C>();
                i = 0;
            }
        }
    }
  if (!cList.isEmpty())
                myCustomDao.save(cList);
```

Comment: `B.getC()`: does it return an iterator? can you post the code of `B`?

Comment: it return list of C items

Comment: but every B has 1mil of C?

Comment: nope just few of them

Comment: if just a few the max number of objects you can have in memory is (commit-interval*B)+(commit-interval*B*C): not a big deal, I think

Comment: yes it is a big deal when in one transaction I load 1 mil records to my app. Then it crashed. So it is no important if there is few or every. Important is that there is option to have 1 mil records

Comment: Does it crash because RDBMS doesn't support a transaction of 1mil recs or because you run OutOfMemoryError?

Comment: out of memory but it doesnt care. I dont want to have some arrayList with 1 mil item. I want to split it to block about 1000 and save it when it reach size then clear it and save again. I updated my qestion how should It look like but I have no idea how to implement this in spring batch

Comment: let me know how will you resolve because I'm interested for my job, too!

Comment: I am new in spring batch and now I have no idea how to solve it. But when our seniors programmer solve this problem I will certainly share about it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If reduce `commit-interval` to a small value in not an option because one B element can have up to 1mil C objects you can do that:

Process class A to class B without creating the C objects in processed B object;
in your `BWriter` attach a `ItemWriteListener<B>.afterWrite()` where you create/save C objects (related to `List<B>` received in listener) one-by-one so your memory consumption in low, but you are guaranted to work in transaction boundaries.

If problem is due to use of Hibernate instead of plain JDBC you can think to use a Stateless session or `flush()/clear()` session manually; 1mil record for a database is not a big number
Unfortunately ORM is not the best choice when you have large amout of data.

My 2 cents, I'm quite new with Spring-batch as you.